# Why my ionic/angular app failed to compile?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm building an App with Angular within Ionic framework, I just finished some firebase configuration using environment.ts and dotenv file ...
when i ran `ionic serve` command it fails to compile the project :/
here's the stack trace in my terminal:

```
[ng] Warning: C:\Users\foo\projects\app\src\environments\environment.ts depends on 'dotenv'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
[ng] For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
[ng]
[ng]
[ng]
[ng] ../../node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js:24:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\foo\node_modules\dotenv\lib'
[ng]
[ng] ../../node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js:25:13-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\foo\node_modules\dotenv\lib'
[ng]
[ng] BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
[ng] This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
[ng] 
[ng] If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
[ng]    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
[ng]    - install 'path-browserify'
[ng] If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
[ng]    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
[ng]
[ng] ../../node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js:26:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\foo\node_modules\dotenv\lib'
[ng]
[ng] BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
[ng] This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
[ng]
[ng] If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
[ng]    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
[ng]    - install 'os-browserify'
[ng] If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
[ng]    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
[ng]
[ng]
[ng] × Failed to compile.
```

*main.ts*

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

*environment.ts*

```
// This file can be replaced during build by using the `fileReplacements` array.
// `ng build` replaces `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts`.
// The list of file replacements can be found in `angular.json`.

require('dotenv').config();

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: process.env["ANGULAR_APP_API_KEY"],
    authDomain: process.env["ANGULAR_APP_DOMAIN"],
    projectId: process.env["ANGULAR_APP_PROJECT_ID"],
    storageBucket: process.env["ANGULAR_APP_BUCKET_ID"],
    messagingSenderId: process.env["ANGULAR_APP_MESSAGING_ID"],
    appId: process.env["ANGULAR_APP_APP_ID"]
  }
};

/*
 * For easier debugging in development mode, you can import the following file
 * to ignore zone related error stack frames such as `zone.run`, `zoneDelegate.invokeTask`.
 *
 * This import should be commented out in production mode because it will have a negative impact
 * on performance if an error is thrown.
 */
// import 'zone.js/plugins/zone-error';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

/**
 * importing firebase tools
 */

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I'm new to ionic framework and his tips and tricks i really appreciate any help

Comment: looks like the issue is related to `dotenv` and not ionic...

Comment: seems like when i remove the require statement from _environment.ts_ it compiles but in the browser console i got this error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` @Andres2142

Comment: Classic example of teaching someone to fish rather than giving them a fish. The very first result from https://www.google.com/search?q=read+process+variables+to+environment.ts